# Tooltips using only CSS

Tags: css, tooltip

I am trying to make a tooltip for an anchor tag using only CSS. I have come [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/mtxJw/) far. I am trying to achieve the functionality of having the box and the tip arrow positioned exactly at the center no matter what the length of the text is.

[image: Gmail's tooltips]

The above image is what I am trying to get at. 
I've tried keeping the `width:auto` but it's not working either.

Comment: Think it may not be possible with just CSS like this. You would need to know the width of the tooltip or be able to position the tooltip area relative to the triangle. Unrelated, but amazingly similar to this: [hint.css](http://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
body
{overflow-x:hidden;}

div
{position:relative;width:700px;border:1px red solid;padding:20px;margin:0 auto;text-align:justify;}

a
{position:relative;white-space:nowrap;}

a > span.tooltip
{
    position: absolute;
    white-space: normal;
    width: 100%;
    top: 130%;
    left: 0;
}

a > span.tooltip > span
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
    left: -500%;
    width: 1100%;
}

a > span.tooltip > span > span
{
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

**DEMO:**
http://jsfiddle.net/b2Yqf/

works on msie 7 8 9 10, firefox, chrome

not what you might want... since markup is made with three nested `<span>`s... but YES. it could be done!

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you're facing is that you need a `white-space: nowrap` this gets you about as far as hint.css by @robooneus. I can't figure out the centering either though. Any widths or margins are relative to the "Tooltip" link's width. A link to where you found the images might be helpful too so we can study the source.

**EDIT1:**
Additionally, a `margin-left: -6px` on the arrow (the :before) centers that on the word tooltip, it counteracts the move to the right by the border.

Comment: The images are definitely pulled from gmail. I pulled it up to see how that was being done, but it is not all CSS. As said, if he knew the width of the tooltip element, he could just use a negative margin equal to half the width to put it in the middle. But with auto width, I don't think it will work.

Comment: the images are from Gmail, you can check it out, it's below the search box. I just used firebug and typed "b".

Comment: @robooneus https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96798895/k.PNG this is what `white-space:nowrap` gives. The only thing that bugs is how to center the tooltip according to the links.

Comment: GMail only really centers the shortest words and it looks like there's some javascript attached there. Their longer tooltips aren't shortened either so I think it's not possible with just CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you are trying to do (center the tooltip) is possible while having `width:auto;`.

If you declare a width, you can simple position the tooltip with:

```
.tooltip:hover:after {
    width:100px; /* whatever you want */
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-50px; /* half the width */
}
```

**EDIT**

As @Alexander says in his answer, also repositioning your tooltip arrow using `margin-left` is a good idea, as it is slightly off center with just `left:50%`.

Comment: `margin:0px` does the trick too, the arrow aligns exactly to the center of the "Tooltip" text. [*edited demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/mtxJw/6/)

Comment: It's actually 6px as your arrow is positioned at 50% of the word "Tooltip" and then pushed right by 6px due to the border. If you carefully scrutinize http://jsfiddle.net/mtxJw/8/ you can see the slight difference.

Comment: Yes, but since it is already 50%, you only want to move it back over by half its width. Unless the triangle width is actually 12px...

Comment: @AnujKaithwas You also changed the left to 40%, margin: 0 doesn't work.

Comment: @AnujKaithwas the updated demo doesn't actually position it in the very middle. width `left:40%;` it is off-center. Plus, consider what happens when your tooltip area is wider... [see this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LNRJg/1/)

Comment: @robooneus You want to move it back the entire amount it got moved to the right. The border causes it to move right 6 px.. Again I refer you to the jsfiddle I linked to, you can see the ^ in a center aligned pointing at the middle, the -3 is slightly to the right of that. The other tooltip which hovers at -6 is at the indicated position..

Comment: Gee, I missed that! I'll remove that @robooneus.

Comment: @AlexanderVarwijk Ah, you are right about moving it 6px... just checked and the triangle is actually 12px wide. For some reason I was thinking it was equilateral. [check the width of .triangle (same thing as the pseudo element)](http://jsfiddle.net/UDR83/). I think we were arguing semantics :P

Comment: @robooneus The triangle is wide 12px because you're adding a border on both sides.